# How to replace double quote character with single quote character in terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm running into a situation where i need terraform to replace this list with strings enclosed in single quotes like this. ['test1','test2']. How would i go about replacing a double quote character with a single quote character? I'm using the replace method, but getting an error when trying to replace with a single quote character. I believe terraform does not support single quotes.  Another thing i would like is to create a new local that holds the string value "'test1','test2'", this is basically removing the square brackets.

```
locals { 
  appengineversions = ["test1","test2"]
  appengine_instances_list = replace(local.appengine,'\"',"\'")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, there is a list with two strings in it. Neither of those strings have **any** quotes in them. The value of the two strings are: `test1` and `test2`. The double quotes in the code are Terraform syntax elements to denote the start and end of a string, they are not part of the actual string values.

Answer (score 1):

So, I couldn't manage to print exactly `['test1','test2']` as you expected but somehow managed to replace double quotes with single quotes.
The reason, why you see double quotes is simply because it's for human readable purposes as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185347/how-to-remove-the-braces-and-quotes-from-output-value-in-terraform).

```
locals {
  appengineversions = ["test1","test2"]
  appengine_instances_list = format("['%s']", join("','", local.appengineversions))  
}

output "test" {
  value = local.appengine_instances_list
}
```

Terraform output ::

> Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
>
> Outputs:
>
> test = "['test1','test2']"

I used [join](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/join) & [format](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/format) functions here to convert list to string & then format accordingly.

Comment: Thanks harsha, this actually worked. I appreciate you helping me. :)

Comment: @cse_and_desist If the answer worked, a good practice is to accept it.